# Xcode constraints how to expand two buttons at the same time?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a view, where I've added two buttons. Both buttons have a constraint to the side of the view(priority:1000). Their width's priority is 560 and they are set to Greater than or equal. Then they are connected with a constraint (priority:1000). Currently the middle constraint is in the center of the view. I want when I switch to side view(iPhone) the buttons to expand their width by the same amount, so that they are both 8px away from the center. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Heights Equally` and `Widths Equally`.

It may help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways how you can achieve that.

The simplest way I see is to set a constraint for the left and right edges instead of having a constraint for width.

However, another way would be to add a constraint "same width" to both buttons. Then they will expand by the same amount.